# Keys with different hash code present in same bucket. C++

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

I created an ordered_map and inserted the following elements

```
  typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> stringMap;   
  stringMap mymap;  
  mymap.insert( {  
            {"house","maison"},  
            {"apple","pomme"},  
            {"tree","arbre"},  
            {"book","livre"},  
            {"door","porte"},  
            {"grapefruit","pamplemousse"}  
            } );
```

When I checked the buckets, I found that there were 7 buckets.

This is what I read:
    The elements of an un_ordered associative container are organized into  buckets. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket

But when I printed the hash code of the keys, I found that there are elements present in a bucket with different hash codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
int main ()  
{  
  typedef std::unordered_multimap<std::string,std::string> stringMap;   
  stringMap mymap;  
  mymap.insert( {  
            {"house","maison"},  
            {"apple","pomme"},  
            {"tree","arbre"},  
            {"book","livre"},  
            {"door","porte"},  
            {"grapefruit","pamplemousse"},  
            } );  

  unsigned n = mymap.bucket_count();  
  unsigned s = mymap.size();  

  std::cout << "mymap has " << n << " buckets.\n";  
  std::cout << "mymap size " << s << " keys.\n";  

  stringMap::hasher fn = mymap.hash_function();  

  for (unsigned i=0; i<n; ++i)  
  {  
    std::cout << "bucket #" << i << " contains: " << std::endl;;  
    for (auto it = mymap.begin(i); it!=mymap.end(i); ++it)  
    {  
      std::cout << "[" << it->first << ":" << it->second << "] ";  
      std::cout << "KEY HASH VALUE: " << fn (it->first) << std::endl;  
    }  

    std::cout << "\n";  
  }  

  return 0;  
}
```

Could anyone please tell, if I'm missing anything and why Elements with different hash codes and present in same bucket.

Results:

```
mymap has 7 buckets.
mymap size 6 keys.
bucket #0 contains: 
[book:livre] KEY HASH VALUE: 4190142187
[house:maison] KEY HASH VALUE: 4227651036

bucket #1 contains: 

bucket #2 contains: 

bucket #3 contains: 
[grapefruit:pamplemousse] KEY HASH VALUE: 3375607049
[tree:arbre] KEY HASH VALUE: 335777326

bucket #4 contains: 

bucket #5 contains: 
[apple:pomme] KEY HASH VALUE: 2758877147

bucket #6 contains: 
[door:porte] KEY HASH VALUE: 3658195372
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket"* `!=` Keys with ***different*** hash codes appear in ***different*** buckets.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. If you have a 32 bit hash code, you don't want 2^32 buckets. Instead, the hash code is mapped to the index of a bucket. For example if you have 7 buckets, an item might use bucket #(hash % 7). So the items with hash codes 0, 7, 14, 21, ... and so on all appear in the same bucket.